# Mouseleave inside or outside mouseenter?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I'm learning basics of jQuery and wwhen I discovered mouseleave and mouseenter actions I started to wonder where should I put mouseleave action? Which1 is more correct and will always work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast','1');
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast','0.25');
        });
    });
});
```

or maybe this1 is better?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast','1');
        });
        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast','0.25');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second option is more correct, it should have a single event setup all the time. Your first option adds a new [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event every time [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) is triggered, leading to many attached events. So use:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 'fast');
});
$('div').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', '0.25');
});
```

There is actually some nice shorthand for this in [`.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

```
$('div').hover(
    function () { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 'fast'); },
    function () { $(this).fadeTo('fast', '0.25'); }
);
```

Comment: dang you beat me by 2 seconds

Comment: Thanks ;) 
btw. look how stupid is first fuction with fadeTo parameters 'fast' + 'fast' :D
I'm making codecademy track so maybe I'll learn about .hover later. Anyway thx ;)